How to retrieve scale factors from geo::AffineTransform in Rust?
I'm using the geo crate (version 0.28.0) in a Rust project and I need to retrieve the amount of scaling in the x and y directions from a geo::AffineTransform instance.
However, after going through the documentation and source code, I couldn't find a direct way to access the scale factors. The internal matrix representation is private, and the public API doesn't seem to expose methods to retrieve the scale factors.
I have tried the following approach:
let [a, b, c, d, tx, ty] = transform.into();
let sx = (a * a + c * c).sqrt()

But this approach assumes knowledge of the internal matrix structure and doesn't work with the public API.
Is there a way to retrieve the scale factors using the existing public API of geo::AffineTransform? Or would I need to modify the crate and submit a pull request to add this functionality?
I'm open to alternative approaches or workarounds if directly retrieving the scale factors is not possible with the current API.

These methods are now public.
https://docs.rs/geo/latest/geo/algorithm/affine_ops/struct.AffineTransform.html#method.new
/// Create a new custom transform matrix
///
/// The argument order matches that of the affine transform matrix:
///```ignore
/// [[a, b, xoff],
///  [d, e, yoff],
///  [0, 0, 1]] <-- not part of the input arguments
/// ```
pub fn new(a: T, b: T, xoff: T, d: T, e: T, yoff: T) -> Self {
    Self([[a, b, xoff], [d, e, yoff], [T::zero(), T::zero(), T::one()]])
}
pub fn a(&self) -> T {
    self.0[0][0]
}
pub fn b(&self) -> T {
    self.0[0][1]
}
pub fn xoff(&self) -> T {
    self.0[0][2]
}
pub fn d(&self) -> T {
    self.0[1][0]
}
pub fn e(&self) -> T {
    self.0[1][1]
}
pub fn yoff(&self) -> T {
    self.0[1][2]
}


You can get tx and ty by applying the transform to (0, 0), then you can get a and d by applying it to (1, 0) and b and e by applying it to (0, 1):
let Coord { x: tx, y: ty } = transform.apply (Coord::zero());
let u = transform.apply (Coord { x: 1.0, y: 0.0 };
let a = u.x - tx;
let d = u.y - ty;
let v = transform.apply (Coord { x: 0.0, y: 1.0 };
let b = v.x - tx;
let e = v.y - ty;

